# Remove/resolve Travis CI weird messages when deploying to npm

Tags: node.js, npm, travis-ci

When package is being deployed to npm registry, some weird additional messages appear on Travis CI console:

Standard messages:

```
Deploying application
NPM API key format changed recently. If your deployment fails, check your API key in ~/.npmrc.
http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/npm/
~/.npmrc size: 48
+ my-package@1.0.0
```

Then weird messages follow:

```
Already up-to-date!
Not currently on any branch.
nothing to commit, working tree clean
Dropped refs/stash@{0} (bff3fdd...1c6d37a)
```

.travis.yml file:

```
dist: trusty
sudo: required

env:
  - CXX="g++-4.8"

addons:
  apt:
    sources:
      - ubuntu-toolchain-r-test
    packages:
      - g++-4.8

language: node_js

node_js:
  - 5
  - 6
  - 7

deploy:
  provider: npm
  email: me@me.xx
  api_key:
    secure: ja...w=
  on:
    tags: true
    branch: master
```

How to get rid of these messages, and also why are they there?

Cheers!

Comment: what's `npm --version` say in the Travis environment? historically Travis has had a pretty ancient version.

Comment: node v7.7.4 npm 4.1.2 nvm 0.33.1 - seems all OK.